# python program creates a google slides presentation but it turns out to be empty

Tags: python, google-slides-api

I have several jpg image files that i need to programmatically insert into a google slides presentation. The first step is to create a program that generates just one slide and inserts one image into the slide. If this is successful, I will amplify the code with a loop over my images. The code is as follows:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import library_JP

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
#SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.readonly']
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations']

# The ID of a sample presentation.
PRESENTATION_ID = '1EAYk18WDjIG-zp_0vLm3CsfQh_i8eXc67Jo2O9C6Vuc'
PRESENTATION_ID = '1tWESMVHXsbbW-rro6wdeDQL3ygkxAf3c0xSd-JK-oXg'
presentation_id = '1tWESMVHXsbbW-rro6wdeDQL3ygkxAf3c0xSd-JK-oXg'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Slides API.
    Prints the number of slides and elments in a sample presentation.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('slides', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Slides API
    IMAGE_URL = ('https://www.google.com/images/branding/'
             'googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png')
#    page_id = '3b330c04-6eb2-11eb-9439-0242ac130002'
    page_id = '0c00dd21-da6d-4b9a-9694-3b9e81b2ab1b'
    requests = [
    {
        'createSlide': {
#            'objectId': page_id,
            'insertionIndex': '1',
            'slideLayoutReference': {
                'predefinedLayout': 'TITLE_AND_TWO_COLUMNS'
            }
        }
    }
              ]


    title = 'JP_february13-2021 '
    print('debug requests before creating pres ',requests)
    body0 = {'title': title}
#
    presentation = service.presentations().create(body=body0).execute()
    print('Created presentation with ID: {0}'.format(
    presentation.get('presentationId')))
    body = { 'requests': requests}
#
    response = service.presentations() \
    .batchUpdate(presentationId=presentation_id, body=body).execute()
    create_slide_response = response.get('replies')[0].get('createSlide')
    print('Created slide with ID: {0}'.format(
    create_slide_response.get('objectId')))
#
    requests = []
    image_id = 'MyImage_01'
    emu4M = {
    'magnitude': 4000000,
    'unit': 'EMU',
            }
    requests.append({
     'createImage': {
        'objectId': image_id,
        'url': IMAGE_URL,
        'elementProperties': {
            'pageObjectId': page_id,
            'size': {
                'height': emu4M,
                'width': emu4M
            },
            'transform': {
                'scaleX': 1,
                'scaleY': 1,
                'translateX': 100000,
                'translateY': 100000,
                'unit': 'EMU'
                         }
            }
                    }
                    })


    response = service.presentations() \
    .batchUpdate(presentationId=presentation_id, body=body).execute()
    create_image_response = response.get('replies')[0].get('createImage')
#    print('Created image with ID: {0}'.format(
#    create_image_response.get('objectId')))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output of the program is :

```
python quickstart_JP5.py
debug requests before creating pres  [{'createSlide': {'insertionIndex': '1', 'slideLayoutReference': {'predefinedLayout': 'TITLE_AND_TWO_COLUMNS'}}}]
Created presentation with ID: 1gRl0h60XXK8_p7kfn4pgBe212ncKHbScj1Y7pesjZlo
Created slide with ID: SLIDES_API1707490034_0
```

However, when I use chrome with the presentation id from above the result is not what I expected:

```
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1gRl0h60XXK8_p7kfn4pgBe212ncKHbScj1Y7pesjZlo/edit#slide=id.p
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `when I use chrome with the presentation id from above the result is not what I expected`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Can you tidy your code a little? It doesn't make sense for instance, that you are doing this `requests = []
    image_id = 'MyImage_01'`  but you have _previously_ set the `body` to requests, and this will not update the body...in this case move `body = { 'requests': requests}`  to just before `response = service.presentations()` - but there are other things like variables declared twice and overwritten, commented out code (you can just remove that for the purposes of this question) - see [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: thank you so much for your help. Meanwhile, I have found out what is wrong in the code. How shall I proceed, should I post the new version and erase the one in the question box?

Comment: If you solved your problem, them post it as an answer below and accept it. If you still having the problem, edit your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following code works as expected and it fixes the issues reported earlier:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
#
# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Slides API.
    Prints the number of slides and elments in a sample presentation.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('slides', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Slides API
    IMAGE_URL = ('https://www.google.com/images/branding/'
             'googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png')


    title = 'JP_february13-2021 '
    body0 = {'title': title}
#
    presentation = service.presentations().create(body=body0).execute()
    print('Created presentation with ID: {0}'.format(
    presentation.get('presentationId')))
    XXX = presentation.get('presentationId')
#
    requests = [
    {
        'createSlide': {
            'insertionIndex': '1',
            'slideLayoutReference': {
                'predefinedLayout': 'TITLE_AND_TWO_COLUMNS'
            }
        }
    }
              ]

    body1 = { 'requests': requests}
#
    response = service.presentations() \
    .batchUpdate(presentationId=XXX, body=body1).execute()
    create_slide_response = response.get('replies')[0].get('createSlide')
    print('Created slide with ID: {0}'.format(
    create_slide_response.get('objectId')))
    YYY = create_slide_response.get('objectId')
#
    requests = []
    image_id = 'MyImage_01'
    emu4M = {
    'magnitude': 4000000,
    'unit': 'EMU',
            }
    requests.append({
     'createImage': {
        'objectId': image_id,
        'url': IMAGE_URL,
        'elementProperties': {
            'pageObjectId': YYY,
            'size': {
                'height': emu4M,
                'width': emu4M
            },
            'transform': {
                'scaleX': 1,
                'scaleY': 1,
                'translateX': 100000,
                'translateY': 100000,
                'unit': 'EMU'
                         }
            }
                    }
                    })

    body2 = {'requests': requests}
    response = service.presentations() \
    .batchUpdate(presentationId=XXX, body=body2).execute()
    create_image_response = response.get('replies')[0].get('createImage')
#    print('Created image with ID: {0}'.format(
#    create_image_response.get('objectId')))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The issue in the original code is that the wrong variable was passed in instructions like:

```
    response = service.presentations() \
    .batchUpdate(presentationId=XXX, body=body1).execute()
```

As a result of the correction, the program returns an address like

```
presentation with ID: 1JHjscoAl3perOnqeJQocpt0YmwHSuXLu5fCgATCY2dc
```

which can be used 'manually' in the url to access the google slides presentation